# How do i finish this button array to make it work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I'm very new to coding and haven't learned anything about buttons so sorry if I'm missing a lot. I don't know how to finish this loop so that when i click the button it cycles through the array i made.

```js
var love = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

for (let i = 0; i < love.length; i++) {
  console.log(love[i])
}


$(".button").on("click", function() {});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
  background: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-3znkSMOAGlw/Tx4Hg9GlDoI/AAAAAAAACgM/X4p_G-yHAiY/s1600/heart_background.jpg);
}

.love {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  ;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: -10px 10px 20px rgba(100, 100, 100, .8);
  ;
}

.button {
  height: 70px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #380002;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 10px rgba(100, 100, 100, .8);
  ;
}
```

```html
<button class=button>New </button>
<div class="love"></div>
```

Comment: Please clear out your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as you want (I think! I'm not 100% what you're looking for). I created a variable `love_ind` that keeps track of where you are in the array, and that is increased with each button press. It also checks if you reach the end of the array and restarts the cycle.

Let me know if this isn't what you were hoping for.

---

## Demo

```js
// Create array
var love = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

// Create an index that we can increase later
var love_ind = 0

// Add click event to button
$(".button").on("click", function() {

  // Change text of the div
  $(".love").text(love[love_ind]);
  
  // Increase index for next button press
  love_ind = love_ind + 1;
  
  // Check if index is greater than the length of the array
  if (love_ind == love.length) {
    
    // Reset index to 0 if it is
    love_ind = 0;
    
  }
  
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
  background: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-3znkSMOAGlw/Tx4Hg9GlDoI/AAAAAAAACgM/X4p_G-yHAiY/s1600/heart_background.jpg);
}

.love {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  ;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: -10px 10px 20px rgba(100, 100, 100, .8);
  ;
}

.button {
  height: 70px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #380002;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 10px rgba(100, 100, 100, .8);
  ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class=button>New</button>
<div class="love"></div>
```

Comment: So I got your code to work in codepen but when i transferred it to my html notepad that I'm working on it wont work. Like the white box pops up where the array items should pop up but it just stays blank. ```var love = ["0", "1", "2", "3"];
     var love_ind = 0
     $(".button").on("click", function() {
     $(".love").text(love[love_ind]);
     love_ind = love_ind + 1;
     if (love_ind == love.length) {
     love_ind = 0;
     }
     });``` 
 Am I typing this up correctly?

Answer (score 1):

First, that's not just javaScript it's jQuery. Second, your question is a bit unclear. You want when you click on the button, to start the for loop and console log ? something like this ? :

```js
var love = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

$(".button").on("click", function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < love.length; i++) {
    console.log(love[i])
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
  background: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-3znkSMOAGlw/Tx4Hg9GlDoI/AAAAAAAACgM/X4p_G-yHAiY/s1600/heart_background.jpg);
}

.love {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  ;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: -10px 10px 20px rgba(100, 100, 100, .8);
  ;
}

.button {
  height: 70px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #380002;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 10px rgba(100, 100, 100, .8);
  ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">New </button>
<div class="love"></div>
```

Comment: If you're looking to cycle through the array all from one button click this is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Move the code for the actions you want to perform within the function body.

```
$(".button").on( "click", function() {
    var love = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
    for (let i = 0; i < love.length; i++) {
        console.log (love[i])
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Declare
const button = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
let love = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

//Global Listener
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
 const target = e.target;
  
  //Check if button
  if(target.classList.contains("button"))
    //Loop
  love.forEach((item, i, array) => console.log(item));
    
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
  background: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-3znkSMOAGlw/Tx4Hg9GlDoI/AAAAAAAACgM/X4p_G-yHAiY/s1600/heart_background.jpg);
}

.love {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  ;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: -10px 10px 20px rgba(100, 100, 100, .8);
  ;
}

.button {
  height: 70px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #380002;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 10px rgba(100, 100, 100, .8);
  ;
}
```

```html
<button class=button>New </button>
<div class="love"></div>
```